# In Java, I get an error when trying to call the method that receives input

Tags: java

When I tried to call my method that receives iStartValue as input, I get an error message about "int iStartValue". I have only been able to call methods that don't receive input (method();), but never able to call a method like this one.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
     ClassMessage cm = new ClassMessage();

     cm.IsMultipleOfEight(int iStartValue);

}
```

Comment: Please read this http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_methods.htm

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `int` in the method call:

```
cm.IsMultipleOfEight(iStartValue);
```

You add the type of the argument when you are defining the method not when calling it.

Also you should define the `iStartValue` somewhere before using it.

e.g.

```
 ClassMessage cm = new ClassMessage();
 int iStartValue = 1; // for example

 // or it can be fetched from a method
 // int iStartValue = getStartValue();

 cm.IsMultipleOfEight(iStartValue);
```

Please read some tutorial on basic Java and how to define and call methods in particular.

Comment: I get another error saying "iStartValue cannot be resolved to a variable"